# How to get bitmap providing a URI, java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /sdcard/Hello/1310610722879.jpg

Tags: android, bitmap, android-contentprovider

I've read the example to do this:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
 {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
     {
         Uri imageUri = data.getData();
         Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),              imageUri);
     }
 }
```

But i get java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /sdcard/Hello/1310610722879.jpg

My code is here:

```
Uri uri1 = Uri.parse(Config.getPhotoPath(this));                
try {
    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri1);
    attachButton.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Any ideas how to make it work?

Ok I messed around, u have to do this:

```
Uri uri1 = Uri.parse("file://" + Config.getPhotoPath(this));
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Ok I messed around, u have to do this:

```
Uri uri1 = Uri.parse("file://" + Config.getPhotoPath(this));
```

Comment: it  would be great is they  can  add that MIME  type  needs to added  manually in api documentation than just  adding  RFC 2396  compliant :/

Comment: I couldnt find the method Config.getPhotoPath(), also you haven't specified imageUri in in your code,how are you still able to retrieve the image ?

Comment: yeh what is Config here??

Answer (score 7):

Or you can do

```
File file = new file(Config.getPhotoPath(this));
Uri uri1 = Uri.fromFile(file);
```